# Avoid making too many nested loops

Tags: loops, fortran

I'm trying to calculate the integer solutions of this equation:

`ax + by + cz = d` for `x, y, z`

with `|ax + by + cz - d| < epsilon`

so I'm trying 1 by 1 the solutions with "DO" like this

```
DO i1=1,max
DO i2=1,max
DO i=1,max
aux=abs(&
 d(1)*tazasmin(1)*i1+d(2)*tazasmin(2)*i2+&
 d(3)*tazasmin(3)*i3+d(4)*tazasmin(4)*i4+d(5)*tazasmin(5)*i5+&
 d(6)*tazasmin(6)*i6 &
+d(7)*tazasmin(7)*i7+d(8)*tazasmin(8)*i8+d(9)*tazasmin(9)*i9&
+d(10)*tazasmin(10)*i10+d(11)*tazasmin(11)*i11+d(12)*tazasmin(12)*i12 &
+d(13)*tazasmin(13)*i13+d(14)*tazasmin(14)*i14&
+d(15)*tazasmin(15)*i15+d(16)*tazasmin(16)*i16-tse)    
    IF (aux<=epsilon) THEN
       //save the solutions.
    END IF
END DO
END DO
END DO
```

I know how to fix the long equation part (to make it elegant and beautiful), but is there a way to avoid the excessive use of DO?

Comment: I'm not an expert on fortran, but this just looks rather convoluted for a simple equation.  `**` is used for power operations, and if this is supposed to be an incremental loop, you can simply define your variables and increment them.  For example, when `i = max` , `i = 1` and `i2 = i2 + 1` until `i2 = max`, then increment `i1` and so on.  This would all happen in a single loop. [Fortan Operators](https://www.obliquity.com/computer/fortran/operate.html)  -- would make this `d = (A**x) + (B**y) + (C**z)`  roughly

Comment: thank you, pst as an answer to take credit gl!

Comment: Not a problem,  while helpful, I don't feel this is a full solution as it isn't written code.  It's more or less logic concepts to follow.  I am glad it helped you  :)   You can post the final code (and summary) of what the final resulting code was that worked for you :)

Comment: one more questions, does "DO i=1,1" repeats itself 2 times?,

Comment: No, `do i = 1, 1` will iterate only once with the value `i=1`.

Comment: The symbol `i` doesn't appear in the expression, is that a typo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing you really want to loop over all 16 values.. try something like this:

```
  implicit none
  integer,parameter  :: nvar = 4
  integer, parameter :: max = 3
  integer varray(nvar)
  integer c,k
  do c=1,max**nvar
     do k=1,nvar            
        varray(k)=mod((c-1)/max**(nvar-k),max)+1
     enddo
! now your expresion is like:
     aux=abs(total(d*tazasmin*varray))
! assuming d and tazasmin are apporpriately declared arrays        
  enddo
  end
```

This calculation will obviously get very big if `max` is large